# Efficient way to move images inside a view with react-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

My goal is to move images inside a view using the accelerometer in an efficient way. I tried to put simple image component and change the style to move them but this is very slow. I thought to use a `WebView` and draw inside a canvas but I don't know how to send to the JavaScript inside the `WebView` the accelerometer data. Do you have something to suggest?

Comment: if you are using low level components like ImageView and it is slow then hiw can you expect html/js code to be faster?

Comment: because the Image component is not made to be moved and animated, instead a canvas is made to do that.

Comment: `ImageView` can be both **moved and animated**, but if it does NOT meet your requirements use a custom `View` and draw whatever you like in its `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method

Comment: I'm looking at react-native documentation and i can't find ImageView (i can only find Image) component and the onDraw event in View documentation

Comment: ok i didn't notice you are using 3rd party framework... then ignore and forget my last comment